# concatenate text from nested siblings if available with the text in the parent node

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract the text from siblings if available and concatenate with the text in parent node. How to do this in xpath?
My HTML shown below has few instances of `<sup> and <sub>`.

my expected output:

```
['2','1/2']
```

Should concatenate like this `['<sup>'+'/'+ '<sub>']`

```
<li data-ingredient="dry+white+wine">
 <span class="qty">2 </span>
 <span class="food">
     "cups"  
     <a href="https://www.test.com">dry white wine</a>
 </span>
</li>
<li data-ingredient="salt">
 <span class="qty">
     <sup>1</sup>
     "⁄"
     <sub>2</sub>
 </span>
 <span class="food"> teaspoon  <a href="https://www.test.com">salt</a>
 </span>
</li>
```

I tried with the below commands and referred multiple Scrapy documentations. but couldn't able to extract the required info.

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="qty"][sup and sub]/text()').extract()
response.xpath('//span[@class="qty"]//sub/text()').extract()
```

Comment: Are you looking for solution with pure xpath? Is it ok if you have solution using javascript?

Comment: is passing to bs4 to handle an option?

Comment: @supputuri ..I am looking for pure xpath command. I am using python

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to iterate by `span.qty`, extract text from there and concatenate it. Like here:

```
txt = """<li data-ingredient="dry+white+wine">
...  <span class="qty">2 </span>
...  <span class="food">
...      "cups"  
...      <a href="https://www.test.com">dry white wine</a>
...  </span>
... </li>
... <li data-ingredient="salt">
...  <span class="qty">
...      <sup>1</sup>
...      "⁄"
...      <sub>2</sub>
...  </span>
...  <span class="food"> teaspoon  <a href="https://www.test.com">salt</a>
...  </span>
... </li>"""
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> sel = Selector(text=txt)
>>> for qty in sel.css('span.qty'):
...     print ''.join([i.replace('"', '').strip() for i in qty.css('::text').extract()])
... 
2
1⁄2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Bs4 for such tasks:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = response.xpath("//li[@data-ingredient='salt']/span[@class='qty']").extract()
soup = BeautifulSoup( html, "html.parser" ).get_text()
```